# how to prevent running same JInternalFrame more than once

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jinternalframe, actionevent

How can you prevent the `JInternalFrame` not to open more once, currently in my application it opens many times. Also how can I make my application run only if there is not the same application running.

This is the code for `JInternalFrame`

```
private void Cash_ButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

    Provider provider = new Provider();
      MainMenu.add (provider);
       provider.setClosable(true);
    }
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a condition and making `provider` a local variable

```
private Provider provider = new Provider();

public Your_Class_Name(){
    provider.setClosable(true);
}

private void Cash_ButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    if(provider.isVisible()) return;
    MainMenu.add (provider);
}
```